# Proof-of-concept: How to dynamically choose an available constructor using reflection in Java

Tags: java, serialization, reflection, deserialization

I'm developing a proof-of-concept object (de-)serialization framework, ideally able to serialize any Object and gather information about the class itself. I started implementing it using Reflection, to:

- Access the type hierarchy (Superclasses, Interfaces, and so on)
- Find all fields on that object, and get all values in that fields

Serializing is the 'easy' part, and can be achieved applying this rule recursively to an object until I found null or primitive types. Now that's where I'm stuck: the deserialization.

Starting with a simple object, the "Hello World" String, I have this serialization:

```
<object type="java.lang.String">
    <primitive name="count" type="int" value="11 />
    <primitive name="hash" type="int" value="0" />
    <primitive name="offset" type="int" value="0" />
    <array name="value" basetype="char">
        <value>H</value>
        <value>e</value>
        <value>l</value>
        ...
        <value>r</value>
        <value>l</value>
        <value>d</value>
    </array>
</object>
```

It's ok to deserialize, because String class has a default constructor and I can call it via Reflection, and I can set all fields. Now, let's suppose I have the following serialization for a object:

```
<object class="some-class-with-no-default-constructor">
    <object name="some-attrib-name" class="attrib-1-class">
    <primitive name="size" type="int" value="5" />
...
</object>
```

What happens if I don't have a default constructor AND all other constructors that receive arguments can't accept 'null' values as input, raising some kind of exception and thus I'm not able to instantiate the class via reflection?

The question is: "Is there a way to instantiate an 'empty object' of some class to set their fields manually after the instantiation without calling its constructors?". I'm open to discuss other strategies too, of course.

Thank you.

---

**EDIT**

Once that it's a proof-of-concept environment, and thus I'm not considering Security restrictions, I've found a way to instantiate any object without calling its constructor, through the Unsafe class.

```
public final class A {
    private final Object o;
    private A(final Object o) { if (o == null) throw new Error(); this.o = o; }
    public static A a() { return new A(new Object()); }
    public Object getO() { return o; }
}
```

This class shown above was proposed in one of the answers below, and it can be instantiated and it's final value set correctly (provided, of course, the security restrictions don't apply), using the following code:

```
private static Unsafe getUnsafe() throws Exception {
    Field vDeclaredField = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredFields()[0];
    vDeclaredField.setAccessible(true);
    Unsafe vUnsafe = (Unsafe) vDeclaredField.get(null);
    vDeclaredField.setAccessible(false);
    return vUnsafe;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    A objectA = (A) getUnsafe().allocateInstance(A.class);

    Field fieldO = A.class.getDeclaredField("o");
    boolean oldAccessibilityValue = fieldO.isAccessible();
    fieldO.setAccessible(true);
    Object objectOParameter = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4); //could be any object
    fieldO.set(objectA, objectOParameter);
    fieldO.setAccessible(oldAccessibilityValue); //I personally prefer setting it to old value

    assert(objectOParameter.equals(objectA.getO()));
}
```

So? Can you guys see any other problems that are not related to SecurityManager itself?

Comment: Serialization in java uses the same unsafe class; nothing prevents doing so; SecurityManager has a quite telling name for a reason, deserialization and accessing private fields is not secure in any shape or for, hence it's left in java framework.

Comment: `fieldO.setAccessible(oldAccessibilityValue); //I personally prefer setting it to old value` this does ABSOLUTELY nothing (and oldAccessibilityValue is always `false`, the method returns only if the accessibility has been overriden). The java.lang.reflect.Field w/ you get is brand new and after the end the `set(object...)` it's no longer available, so setting has no effect, morealso you will want to cache the fields or if you actually go for Unsafe route, just stick w/ it (it has the same abilities like java.lang.reflect.Field)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't be done reliably.

Suppose you have the following class:

```
public final class A {
    private final Object o;
    private A(final Object o) { if (o == null) throw new Error(); this.o = o; }
    public static A a() { return new A(new Object()); }
    public Object getO() { return o; }
}
```

First of all, you have the problem you mention about a non-default constructor, which takes an argument, and will throw an exception when given `null`.

Second, the argument to the constructor can (in this case will) define the value of a **final** instance field, which you cannot reliably control after the object has been built (either because of the memory model semantics of final fields that may cause visibility problems had the object already been published to other threads, or because of a `SecurityManager` that won't allow you to modify the final field).

Finally, the constructor is **private** (or protected, or package-protected, whatever). If there's a security manager installed, it might completely block your attempts to `setAccessible(true)` on the constructor, so that you could force it to be called.

So, I'd either simply drop the project as you propose, or make some restrictions on the characteristics of the objects that your framework can (de)serialize.

As a final consideration, *serialization* is not simply the process of saving and restoring fields. It's something that must be carefully planned and implemented during the design of a class. **A class must be designed to be serializable**.

---

**REPLY TO EDIT**

It would not be fair to call the code you provide "pure Java", since it uses the non-standard
API "sun.misc.Unsafe", that is present in Sun's implementation but not guaranteed to be present in all implementations. The code is, therefore, dependent on the implementation.

In the test code you wrote, it is assumed knowledge about the class, ie, you use getDeclaredField("o"). Anyway, I think this could easily be fixed.

However, I see two problems.

### Thou shall not serialize system resources

First of all, suppose I have a class like this:

```
class StockQuoteProvider {
    private QuoteCache cache;
    private Thread quoteCacheUpdater;
    public StockQuoteProvider() {
        this.quoteCacheUpdater = ... // sets up a Thread that will use sockets to connect to Yahoo's stock quote provider and update the cache periodically
        this.quoteCacheUpdater.start();
    }
    public Quote getQuote(final String symbol) { return ... }
}
```

How can you possibly serialize a `Thread`? What would be the semantics of the serialized object? What if the thread is in the middle of an IO operation, like reading from the socket? How would you *serialize the socket connection*?! It makes no sense. And this class is quite a normal one.

### Thou shall not share deserialized instances without synchronization, even if the class is perfectly thread-safe

Let's forget about semantics, and get back to the language specification, and find another problem with your approach. (**edit:** changed the class to make the point even stronger). Consider the following class, which represents a mutable range of integers:

```
// Represents a range of integers, {a, a+1, ..., b}, in which a < b.
class Range {
  private final Object lock = new Object();
  private int a;
  private int b;
  Range(final int a, final int b) { setAB(a, b); }
  final int[] getAB() { synchronized(lock) { return new int[]{a, b}; } }
  final void setAB(final int a, final int b) {
    if (!(a < b)) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid range"); }
    synchronized(lock) { this.a = a; this.b = b; }
  }
  @Override public String toString() {
    int[] ab = getAB();
    int a = ab[0];
    int b = ab[1];
    return a + " < " + b;
  }
}
```

A very simple, innocent-looking class, right? Note that the array int[] is used as the return type of the getter since if we use a couple of getters, the values of `a` and `b` might change between the two calls to the getter.

So, this class is perfectly thread-safe. Under "normal" circumstances, it cannot possibly be in a state such that "a >= b".

By using the deserialization technique proposed by the OP, this guarantee disappears. Suppose the OP gave me 2 methods, a "Object serialize(Object o)", and a "Object deserialize(Object o)", which uses the algorithm proposed. The following pseudo-code will prove it does not work:

```
public class Test {
  public static Range r = null;
  public static void Main(final String[] args) {
    final Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override void run() { r = deserialize(serialize(new Range(1, 3)); }
    });

    final Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override void run() { System.out.println(r); }
    });

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
```

What will it print? First of all, **it *can* print null**, if the write to the field `r` is not seen by T2. To make things more interesting (and see how subtle this can get), let's suppose T2 actually sees this write to the field `r`. Since the deserialization process provide no synchronization, the JVM is free to reorder the writes to the fields inside the newly deserialized `Range` instance at its will. So, **it *can* print "0 < 0"** if T2 sees none of the writes to `a` and `b`, or **"1 < 0"** (if it sees only the write to a), or **"0 < 3"** or **"1 < 3"**. According to the Java Language Specification, you cannot possibly predict the outcome (your only guarantee is that the outcome must be one of this 5 possibilities).

So, the point is: you cannot possibly make this work reliably for every single class. I can always hide a lock acquisition, and you wouldn't be able to trace it (without some serious, hardcore, (impossible?) bytecode analysis) so the deserialized version of the class would not be seen equally by every thread... can you see the huge problems that can appear?

### To sum up...

Such a framework cannot exist. You will have problems with security managers (the use of `setAccessible(true)`), with portability of your code (the use of `sun.misc.Unsafe`), with multi-threading (`class Range`), with no-sense, unusable deserialized instances (`class StockQuoteProvider`). These are only the first 4 problems I could come up with, and that cannot be solved with a pure Java code and without absolutely no assumptions on the objects being serialized.

So, the conclusion is that you **must** restrict the objects that your framework will be able to serialize. In other words, the objects must be designed to be serializable objects.

Good luck.

Comment: I'm aware since the beggining that this proof of concept shouldn't go into a production environment, among other things, because of these SecurityManager points. I also agree that Serialization have to be done under some restrictions, but was just wondering if there is a possibility (any one) to do it. With some research, I found something. Where can I put it? Is it allowed to edit my original question?

Comment: Sure, you can edit you question, go on! There should be an "edit" link following your question. I do really want to see what you came up with. Is it pure Java? If so, I'd be glad to try to provide you with a simple class that would break the new method you devised, even if we ignore the "security manager problem" :). Have you taken into consideration the visibility of the fields by different threads?

Comment: Yes, is it pure Java. In fact, I have not tested this visibility by other threads, I'm editing now the original post. Let's us see if we can discuss something on it.

Comment: You provided very valuable points while restricting this use for "all objects". However, even this way, it's more COMMON, being not a rule, of course, to serialize more simple objects (i.e., objects that carries data, such as POJO). And this serialization should be used to store this kind of objects, don't making sense the serialization of classes that do processing instead of storing data. Of course your points are all right. Thanks by the response!

Comment: And about the lock, just remember I'm using reflection to access the fields directly, not the methods, so, I don't even access the synchronized code, do I?

Comment: @Bruno: actually, without doing bytecode analysis, you can't even know that there's lock acquisition going on. Here,the problem is that when setting a field from one thread, without synchronization, other threads might not be aware of the modification. To be more precise, for a thread T2 to see a write W(F) to a field F made by another thread T1, the following must occur in this exact order: T1 acquires a lock L, T1 executes W(F), T1 releases the lock L, T2 acquires **the same** lock L, then T2 reads F. Even if you synchronize, but on different locks, than it's not sure that T2 sees the write!

Comment: @Bruno: to learn more about the visibility of fields, you could try to decipher the [chapter 17 of the Java Language Specification, 3rd edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html) or, if you don't like to suffer, you could read Java Concurrency in Practice.

Comment: @Bruno: About your concurrency example, I think there should be no problem. The only question would be whether the thread is accessing the old or new `b`, but in each case the field would be initialized before the thread started, i.e. it would even work without any lock.

Comment: @Paulo: the problem is exactly what you stated in your comment: you don't know which value the thread will observe! Suppose you had not 1, but 2 fields on the class, and some restriction on their values (ie, int x < int y, at all times). It is totally possible for another thread see the default value for y, and a deserialized value of, say, 3 for x, violating the invariant!! Can you imagine the huge amount of problems this can create?!

Comment: @Paulo: unless you properly synchronize, always using the appropriate locks when accessing (reading or writing) fields, you cannot possibly share an instance of your class among multiple threads. Therefore, as I stated, without some highly sophisticated (impossible?) bytecode analysis that would identify the locks being used, the deserialization proposed by the OP cannot be done reliably.

Comment: @Paulo: I've just changed the threading example in the answer. I hope this new one will better illustrate my point.

Comment: (note that the problem discussed is precisely the same as before: the impossibility to know which writes by a thread will be seen by another)

Comment: @Bruno, @Paulo: Just to clarify, when I thought about this proof-of-concept, I was not considering the lifecycle of an object (concurrency, restriction between values...), but only the data itself, with purposes of data analysis, storage or interoperability with other language, and so on... Now I understood all points discussed here and I'm convinced that it can't be made without criteria (i.e., applying at least some restriction). Thanks by your help!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to instantiate an
>   'empty object' of some class to set
>   their fields manually after the
>   instantiation without calling its
>   constructors?

No, there isn't. Which is exactly why reflection-based frameworks or libraries generally require the classes they work with to adhere to the JavaBeans specification, which requires a default constructor.

One way to overcome this would be to require metadata of some sort (annotations, xml) for classes that don't have a default constructor, which tells you what constructor to call with what values.

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection, there is no reliable way, although you can take educated guesses based on the parameter types of declared constructors.

You could check out [Objenesis](http://objenesis.googlecode.com/svn/docs/index.html).

Also you could look into [manipulating the byte code at run-time](http://www.java2s.com/Product/Java/Byte-Source-Code/Byte-Code-Edit.htm).

Comment: "educated guesses"?! Java is an Object Oriented Programming language, not a **Lucky Oriented Programming** language!